# Custom expiration date directive throwing rootScope digest error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-rootscope

I have 2 input fields that need to get validated after both fields have been entered. It's a credit card expiration date, so theres a `month` and `year`. I'm using a third-party service to actually do the validation.

Therefore, I setup 3 directives: `exp`, `expMonth`, and `expYear`.

I use a `$watch` to validate the user input - however I would like to show an error if the validation is false. **When I attempt to do `ng-class` with the `exampleForm.$error.expiry`, I get `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached.`**

**Here is a demo**
http://plnkr.co/edit/SSiSfLB8hEEb4mrdgaoO?p=preview

**view.html**

```
  <form name='exampleForm' novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'is-invalid': exampleForm.$error.expiry }">
       <div class="expiration-wrapper" exp>
          <input type='text' ng-model='data.year' name='year' exp-month />
          <input type='text' ng-model='data.month' name='month' exp-year />
       </div>
    </div>
```

**exp.directive.js**

```
  angular.module('example')
    .directive('exp', ['ThirdPartyValidationService',
      function(ThirdPartyValidationService) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: 'exp',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.watch();
          },
          controller: function($scope, $element, ThirdPartyValidationService) {
            var self = this;
            var parentForm = $element.inheritedData('$formController');
            var ngModel = {
              year: {},
              month: {}
            };

            var setValidity = function(exp) {
              var expMonth = exp.month;
              var expYear = exp.year;
              var valid = ThirdPartyValidationService.validateExpiry(expMonth, expYear);

              parentForm.$setValidity('expiry', valid, $element);
            };

            self.setMonth(monthCtrl) {
              ngModel.month = monthCtrl;
            };

            self.setYear(yearCtrl) {
              ngModel.year = yearCtrl;
            };

            self.watch = function() {
              $scope.$watch(function() {
                return {
                  month: ngModel.month.$modelValue,
                  year: ngModel.year.$modelValue
                };
              }, setValidity, true);
            };
          }
        };
      }]);
```

**expMonth.directive.js**

```
    angular.module('example')
      .directive('expMonth', [
        function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ['ngModel', '^?exp'],
            compile: function(element, attributes) {
              return function(scope, element, attributes, controllers) {

                var formCtrl = controllers[0];
                var expMonthCtrl = controllers[1];

                expMonthCtrl.setMonth(formCtrl);
              };
            };
          };

        }]);
```

**expYear.directive.js**

```
    angular.module('example')
      .directive('expYear', [
        function() {
          return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ['ngModel', '^?exp'],
            compile: function(element, attributes) {
              return function(scope, element, attributes, controllers) {

                var formCtrl = controllers[0];
                var expYearCtrl = controllers[1];

                expYearCtrl.setYear(formCtrl);
              };
            };
          };

        }]);
```

Comment: When you get the infinite digest exception, it also logs the last _x_ watch expressions evaluated in the console. Can you post that list? Also, if you can reproduce this in [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co) or some other such tool, that would be helpful for us to diagnose.

Comment: A few other comments: 1) What version of AngularJS are you using? 2) I assume in your markup the directives are actually `exp-month` and `exp-year` (not camel case as you had it). 3) If you log the arguments to the `setValidity()` function, what do you notice about the difference between the new value (1st arg) and old value (2nd arg)?

Comment: Added a plunkr.  http://plnkr.co/edit/SSiSfLB8hEEb4mrdgaoO?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the validity error to a jquery selection with the line:

```
parentForm.$setValidity('expiry', valid, $element);
```

Then you are watching that jQuery element via `ng-class` when you have:

```
ng-class="{ 'is-invalid' : exampleForm.$error.expiry }"
```

in your markup. This causes strange exceptions to be thrown when angular tries to deep copy this value.

Instead, change it to use the `.length` property of the jQuery object instead. If non-zero (truthy), the `is-invalid` class will be set correctly, otherwise it won't be.

```
ng-class="{ 'is-invalid' : exampleForm.$error.expiry.length }"
```

You could also do `...expiry.length > 0` if that makes more sense to you and future developers who have to look at your code.

I [forked your Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HJgJzmWCQQAv3ehBSigA?p=preview) so it works with this change.

Comment: Thank you so much. Makes alot of sense.